# Why does harmonic series diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

A series is said to be convergent if $$\left|\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}\right| \leq1$$
where $U_n$ denotes $n$th term of the series. If we denote the sum upto $j$th term of the Harmonic series by $H_j$, then $$H_j=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{j}$$
where $j\geq1$. There's a formal proof to show that this series diverges, but from the ratio test of convergent series, we get $$\left|\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}\right|=\left|\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{\frac{1}{n}}\right|=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n+1}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}=1$$
which clearly shows that this is a convergent series. What am I missing here? It's impossible for a series to be both convergent and divergent at the same time. Please provide me some insight to this problem.

Comment: The ratio test is inconclusive when the limit is $1$. In this case the series may be divergent, conditionally convergent, or absolutely convergent. See [this](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/RatioTest.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first display is incorrect.  The [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) guarantees convergence if the inequality in your first display is strict.  It makes no statement about convergence/divergence when the limit of the ratio of successive terms is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Cauchy.  Consider, given $N$, $|S_{2N}-S_N|=1/(2N)+\dots+1/(N+1)\ge N\cdot 1/(2N)=1/2$.